# ASP.NET Populating Listbox issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

As of right now I am trying to create an ASP.NET page which will list books from a category, in a listbox based upon which category button you choose and then I have another two buttons (one for DESC order and one for ASC order). Now the issue is when I click on the ASC or DESC button after hitting the fiction button and populating the list box it wipes the list box.

I posted a similar question earlier, got some fixes, but it is still wiping the listbox when I hit the ASC or DESC buttons.

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET so simple or "newb-friendly" explanations and code-examples/fixes are very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Code Below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class partin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private List<String> books = new List<String>();

void Page_PreRender()
{
    Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
    Item_Listbox.DataBind();   
}

int SortASC(string x, string y)
{
    return String.Compare(x, y);
}

int SortDESC(string x, string y)
{
    return String.Compare(x, y) * -1;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        Header_Label.Text = "Welcome! Please select a book category.";
        Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
        Item_Listbox.DataBind();

    }

}

protected void Fiction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        Header_Label.Text = "Fiction Section";

        books.Add("Title: The Old Man and The Sea | Decription: An epic novel. | Price: 10 USD | Quantity: 3");
        books.Add("Title: A Game of Thrones | Decription: A tale of fire and ice. | Price: 15 USD | Quantity: 6");
        books.Add("Title: Dracula | Decription: A book about vampires. | Price: 5 USD | Quantity: 7");
        books.Add("Title: Twilight | Decription: An awful book. | Price: Free | Quantity: 1000");

        Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
        Item_Listbox.DataBind();

}


protected void Non_Fiction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Header_Label.Text = "Non-Fiction Section";



}
protected void Self_Help_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Header_Label.Text = "Self Help Section";



}

protected void Sort_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Sort")
    {
        switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        {
            case "ASC":
                books.Sort(SortASC);
                break;
            case "DESC":
                books.Sort(SortDESC);
                break;
        }

    }
    Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
    Item_Listbox.DataBind();  
}



}
```

ASPX Code:

```
    &nbsp;<asp:Panel 
        ID="Navigation" runat="server" Height="276px" Width="197px" 
        CssClass="Navigation" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Double">
    <asp:Button ID="Fiction" runat="server" Text="Fiction" Width="145px" 
            CssClass="Nav_buttons" onclick="Fiction_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Non_Fiction" runat="server" Text="Non-Fiction" Width="145px" 
            CssClass="Nav_buttons" onclick="Non_Fiction_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Self_Help" runat="server" Text="Self Help" Width="145px" 
            CssClass="Nav_buttons" onclick="Self_Help_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="New_Item" runat="server" Text="Add New Item" Width="145px" CssClass="Nav_buttons" />        
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Books_Panel" runat="server" CssClass="Books_Panel" Height="409px" 
        BorderStyle="Double">
        <asp:Label ID="Header_Label" runat="server" 
            style="top: 79px; left: 693px; position: absolute; height: 19px; width: 234px" 
            Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        <asp:ListBox ID="Item_Listbox" runat="server" 


            style="top: 204px; left: 443px; position: absolute; height: 136px; width: 732px" 
            AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:ListBox>

        <asp:Button ID="Ascending_Button" runat="server" 
            style="top: 375px; left: 723px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 169px" 
            Text="Ascending Order" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ASC" 
            OnCommand="Sort_Command" />

        <asp:Button ID="Descending_Button" runat="server" 
            style="top: 405px; left: 723px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 169px" 
            Text="Descending Order" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="DESC" 
            OnCommand="Sort_Command" />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="Cat_Menu" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Can you post your aspx markup?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on ASC or DESC button to sort the list it goes to sort handler but here `books` is empty on page postback so the empty datasource is bound to the list.

You should either rebind the source or maintain it in a viewstate so that it can be used on page post back.

Try something like this.

```
private List<String> books
{ 
   get{
         if(ViewState["books"] == null){
             List<String> books = new List<String>();
             books.Add("Title: The Old Man and The Sea | Decription: An epic novel. | Price: 10 USD | Quantity: 3");
            books.Add("Title: A Game of Thrones | Decription: A tale of fire and ice. | Price: 15 USD | Quantity: 6");
            books.Add("Title: Dracula | Decription: A book about vampires. | Price: 5 USD | Quantity: 7");
            books.Add("Title: Twilight | Decription: An awful book. | Price: Free | Quantity: 1000");
             ViewState["books"] = books;
         }
         return new List<String>((String[])ViewState["books"]);
   }
   set{
       ViewState["books"] = value;
   }
}

protected void Fiction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Header_Label.Text = "Fiction Section";

        Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
        Item_Listbox.DataBind();
}

protected void Sort_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Sort")
    {
        switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        {
            case "ASC":
                books.Sort(SortASC);
                break;
            case "DESC":
                books.Sort(SortDESC);
                break;
        }

    }

    Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
    Item_Listbox.DataBind();  
}
```

Comment: As I said I'm a novice and from what I understand the viewstate would make sense as when I walked through it, it seemed the data was going no where. I tried what you suggested though and I am recieving this error now:

Comment: Try my edited answer, changed `string` to `String` while casting.

Comment: The issue I am having now is that it is still clearing the listbox once I hit the ASC or DESC button (after clicking the fiction button first and populating the listbox)

Comment: Thanks I'll have to give this a go in a bit. My question is though would this no longer allow me to update the list via different button clicks (categories) since it will add those books every time?

Comment: I tried it out I am getting an invalid cast exception on this line though:

Comment: return new List<String>((String[])ViewState["books"]);